# Can I change the "fixup!" keyword for Git's autosquash?

Tags: git

Is there a way to change Git's `autosquash` to look for something other than `fixup!` to automatically fixup a commit? I'm lazy and usually just write `f` for a commit to signify that I need to later fixup the commit. It'd be nice to be able to change Git to look for a commit message of `f` instead of `fixup!` when running an `autosquash`, so I don't have to fix them up manually.

Is this value configurable anywhere?

Comment: `fixup!` text is usually written by `git commit --fixup` so you don't need to write it manually.

Answer (score 3):

No: the autosquash code looks for literal `squash!` and `fixup!` strings, and then takes the rest of the subject line and looks for matching commits.  If you make the commits with `git commit --squash` or `git commit --fixup` and provide the identity of the commit you intend to squash-with or fix, Git will fill in the subject (`--squash`) or entire text (`--fixup`) as appropriate.

Comment: hm... is there a way to find commits with the title `f` in my branch and run `git commit --fixup` on all of them? that would work for me.

Comment: If `feedbad` is a commit whose subject is `f earlier commit`, `git commit --fixup` would make a *new* commit whose subject is `fixup! f earlier commit` (and ID is not `feedbad` but `feedbad` is still in the commit chain). In other words if you've already made the fixup commit, it's too late. You could use `git commit --amend` or `git rebase -i` to copy it to a new commit with a different message, but by this point, you might as well do the manual `git rebase -i` and turn it into a fixup commit in the right place.